# How to make api in react select

Tags: reactjs

This is my code

My state

```
this.state = {
    loading: true,
    weather: [],
    cityName: [],
    selectedOption: '',

}
```

My call api

```
const getAPIcityName = Axios.get('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/topcities/100?').then((res) => {
        console.log('res' + res);
        this.setState({ cityName: res.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
    });
}
```

And here i wont to do the Select the name of the city

```
handleChange(selectedOption) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(selectedOption);
}

render() {
    let options = this.state.cityName.map((cityName) => {
        return cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName;
    })

    return (
        <div class="container">

            <h1 for="Search">Search</h1>
            <form>

                <Select
                    name="form-field-name"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    options={options}
                />
```

**And here it works**

```
{/* <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
    {this.state.cityName.map(cityName => <option key={cityName.Key}>{cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName}</option>)}
</select> */}
```

And this is **the Error**

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'LocalizedName' of undefined

Comment: `cityName.AdministrativeArea` is `undefined`, that's why you are getting that error. you need to initialize it in your constructor or await your API call.

Comment: What is the structure of the cityName array?

Comment: Hi Itzik, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are using [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home).

`react-select` needs `options` array in the following format,

```
const options = [
  { value: '', label: '' },
  { value: '', label: '' },
  ...
]
```

Your options should be in above format.

As your data is coming from an API, you need to first check if you have data in state and then only iterate over the state to get `options`

```
let options = [];

if(this.state.cityName && this.state.cityName.length > 0){
   options = this.state.cityName.map((cityName) => {
        return {value: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName, label: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName};
    })
}
```